# Xamarin Forms: Not getting response form HTTP Client

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make REST request from my application to a local server. After I do the post request I am not getting the response neither am I getting any error. I am not understanding what is happening or what mistake am I doing. Below is my Post Request Code:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task registerUser(String enteredUserName, String enteredEmail, String enteredPhone, String enteredPass)
        {
    string url = "http://192.168.0.63:6969/musersAdd";
    string result = String.Empty;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("emp_name", enteredUserName),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", enteredPass),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("emp_email", enteredEmail),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("emp_mobile", enteredPhone)
        });

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("The value of result is {resultContent}", resultContent);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added break point to the if statement, but the code after the line `client.PostAsync` never gets executed.

Please let me know what mistake am I doing.

Comment: That is because exception is thrown and swallowed somewhere. Put try-catch around entire body of method and see if you can catch any exception.

Comment: @focus: You're probably [blocking on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @focus do you get the solution for this problem??